# Output is blurry when printing out labels on a laser printer

Tags: printing, laser-printer, label-printer

I have a laser printer, a Samsung CLP-415NW. The quality is perfect on regular plater, but once I try to print on labels, it looks like the picture. The printing is not so great.

This especially happens to big labels, like DIN-A5 labels (2x on DIN-A4). Is this just the way it is, or do I just have to purchase different kinds of labels in order to print on them with good quality and without damaging the printer?

Does this even damage the printer? Or should I simply not care and print anyway? The quality only has to be good enough so my postal labels are recognized by scanners.

---

- **Top:** Printed on a label.
- **Bottom:** Printed on paper.

[image: example]

Comment: As long as the label stock is designed for laser printers (e.g., won't melt), and it feeds properly, it shouldn't damage your printer.  The poor print quality could be due to a number of potential problems, including rough surface texture, the stock is too thick, or the paper is coated to make it weatherproof and the toner doesn't adhere well to the coating.  I would experiment with other label stock.  Also, verify that it's coming out of the printer like that, not rubbing off in handling.

Comment: I tried two different ones, both designed for inkjet as well as laser printers. Also I see ghost copies of the barcode 10cm next to them, because the color somehow seem to "stick" to the toners. I don't think this is a good sign...

Comment: If you get a good output on paper, it's got to be the label stock that's giving the printer indigestion.

Comment: I already came to this conclusion. But what should I do about it - Should I just ignore it and hope my printer doesn't get toner cancer from it, or should I seek different labels?

Comment: It shouldn't hurt the printer but the barcodes might be hard to scan.  Experiment with different labels.  Try ones specifically designed for laser printers rather than general purpose, different stock weights, etc.  Some companies print on plain paper and then glue or tape it on.  See if the printer driver has a setting for labels or thick stock.  Consider getting another printer (B&W lasers ~$100).  Take some label stock to a computer store and do a sample print on it to find one that works well.  Ask Samsung tech support for recommendations on labels that work well.

Comment: One more thought -- are you using genuine Samsung toner or a third party product?  Toner varies in characteristics like grain size, melting point, etc.  If you're using another brand, it might be adequate for plain paper but not close enough to work well on challenging stock (in which case, the solution might be to use the genuine stuff).

Comment: I always use genuine stuff for these reasons...

Comment: "Paper weight" or rather *thickness* does matter, better check how thick sheets (labels+base!) you have and what the printer does accept. Too thick things might cause mechanical trouble - which might be what you see the effects of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are usually a lot thicker and heavier than bond paper. That means the printer will need to apply more heat to fuse the toner properly. To accommodate this, most printers let you select different paper types.

The  CLP-415NW data sheet lists the following paper types: Plain, Thin, Thick, Cardstock, Hole Punched, Transparency, Preprinted, Letterhead, Recycled, Archive, Bond, Label, Envelope, Cotton, Colored, Glossy, Thicker Paper.

If you are printing using a driver (e.g. Windows) then you can select the type in printer properties.